# Seaborn bar plot with regression line query

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, regression

I am trying to produce a bar plot with a line of regression. I am trying to follow a previous suggestion for the same problem but get an error message that I am unable to overcome. My script is as follows:

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

sns.set(style="white", context="score")


data = {'Days':  ['5', '10', '15', '20'],
        'Impact': ['33.7561', '30.6281', '29.5748', '29.0482']
        }

a = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Days','Impact'])

print (a)

ax = sns.barplot(data=a, x=a.Days, y=a.Impact, color='lightblue' )
# put bars in background:
for c in ax.patches:
    c.set_zorder(0)
# plot regplot with numbers 0,..,len(a) as x value
sns.regplot(x=np.arange(0,len(a)), y=a.Impact, ax=ax)
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=False)
ax.set_ylabel("")
ax.set_xticklabels(['5', '10','15','20'])
plt.show()
```

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)

  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3162, in run_cell_async
    self.displayhook.exec_result = result

  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 604, in __set__
    self.set(obj, value)

  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 578, in set
    new_value = self._validate(obj, value)

  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 610, in _validate
    value = self.validate(obj, value)

  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1842, in validate
    if isinstance(value, self.klass):

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 54
```

but I am not sure what this means. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add you full error trace. Especially as it seems like the error might have nothing to do with the plotting part of the script...In fact, running your code I get an error on the `sns.set` line. That might be a matter of module versions, but it's still not the error you're reporting.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I will edit the question now.

Comment: As suspected, the error seems to be pointing to a different part of your code. Are you sure running this code on its own produces that error? Again - I get a different error when running the snippet you posted

Comment: Yes, I don't think I had installed the seaborn module since upgrading my python package. My error went away after I did this. Thank you, this helped me realize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure you supply `int` or `float` in the `df`

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Days':  [5, 10, 15, 20],
        'Impact': [33.7561, 30.6281, 29.5748, 29.0482]
        }

a = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Days','Impact'])

print (a)

ax = sns.barplot(data=a, x='Days', y='Impact', color='lightblue' )
# put bars in background:
for c in ax.patches:
    c.set_zorder(0)
# plot regplot with numbers 0,..,len(a) as x value

ax = sns.regplot(x=np.arange(0,len(a)), y=a['Impact'], marker="+")
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=False)
ax.set_ylabel("")
ax.set_xticklabels(['5', '10','15','20'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that resolved the problem! Do you know what I would need to change in the code to make a curve that will fit the data instead of line?

Comment: Can you accept this but clicking the `tick` button of this suggestion solve your issue. Please open a new post for this particular request and tag me on it

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have ticked it now and asked a new question but Im not sure how to tag you.